# Chaos Toolkit support for CRI-O based runtimes? for instance will it work on OpenShift Container Platform v4.3 please?

Tags: openshift, chaos, resiliency

Please can someone confirm if Chaos Toolkit (https://github.com/chaostoolkit) will work on OpenShift Container Platform version 4.3 please? which is based on CRI-O runtime. As previously had tried it with Gremlin, Ops-Monkey, Pumba and Litmus but none of them seem to work and the reason attributed appears to be the CRI-O runtimes. Appreciate if someone can confirm if Chaos Toolkit will definitely work on OCP v4.3? and also can suggest any other OpenSource alternatives that are out there please? thanks again.

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Litmus supports CRI-O runtime from Release 1.10.0.